# i want convert bios tree to preorder doubly link list in c

Tags: c, tree

Given a Binary Tree (Bt), convert it to a Doubly Linked List(DLL). The left and right pointers in nodes are to be used as previous and next pointers respectively in the converted DLL.

I want to change tree to a double link list, without changing the tree
code I wrote.  But it doesn't (...) in a preorder (...).
How I can convert them?
I also tried to do it with "qunqe" (?); and It didn't succeed so I move to "req" (?).
I hope you can help me.

Thank you.

```
node* bintree2list(node *roott)
{
    //don't have tree
    if (roott == NULL)
        return roott;
    // Convert
    roott = bintree2listUtil(roott);

    while (roott->left != NULL) // go to the begining to root
        roott = roott->left;
    return (roott);
}

node* bintree2listUtil(node* root)
{
    if (root == NULL)
        return root;

    if (root->left != NULL)
    {
        node*left = bintree2listUtil(root->left);
        for (; left->right != NULL; left = left->right);
        left->right = root;
        root->left = left;
    }

    if (root->right != NULL)
    {
        node* right = bintree2listUtil(root->right);
        for (; right->left != NULL; right = right->left);
        root->right = right;
        right->left = root;

    }
    return root;
}
```

Comment: Please give sample input with desired output. The kind of binary trees I know do not turn into the kind of double-linked lists I know by considering left to be previous and right to be next. For example, in the kind of linked lists I know, something->next->previous==something. At least if all involved pointers are not NULL.

Comment: I improved your question as much as possible. Please click "[edit]" to rework the places where I inserted "(...)" (missing some word) and "(?)" (unknown term, at least unknown to me). And for any future participation at StackOverflow, please develop the habit of reading your posts afterwards and using [edit] to improve any mistakes you find.

Comment: Taking the [tour] would be an appreciated gesture, reflecting your intention to learn about the etiquette at StackOveflow.

Comment: Are the concepts of recursion and tree-traversal already known to you?

Comment: Guessing at sample input: "((1) 2 (3)) 4 ((5) 6 (7))" and desired output "1<>2<>3<>4<>5<>6<>7". Correct? Please use this to make a [mcve].

Comment: When editing the question, please make sure to show the result of the current code and to explain what is wrong about it.